# Need to compare string which has one or more word dynamic

Tags: c#, string

I am validation string in c#(Pattern).

The thing is with validation is, it contains one or more word dynamic

For Example :

First String - **New** Ticket Update- **ID:New** with Priority:**New** A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

Second string -**#** Ticket Update- ID:**#** with Priority:**#** A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

I have a second string with me in my DB and I have replaced the dynamic word with **#** it can be anything.

And the First string is coming for Validating if it matches the pattern given in the second string.

I know it can be done using string splitting operation but do we have any alternate method for this to be efficient because splitting operation we be heavy, like can we do it with regex or other thing.

IF First string is : **AnyWordWithNumbers** Ticket Update- ID:**AnyWordWithNumbers** with Priority:**AnyWordWithNumbers** A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

So this string is valid..
IF First string is : **AnyWordWithNumbers** Tt Update- ID:**AnyWordWithNumbers** with Priority:**AnyWordWithNumbers** A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD

Which is missing last (.) and the spelling of ticket is incorrect it is not valid.

Not : Mark in bold word can be anything

Comment: Are you saying that the text other than the key word "AnyWordWithnumbers" are fixed (including the space between them)?

Comment: @user1719227 I wish you'd made it clearer that each "AnyWordWithNumbers" could be different.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to keep your questions clean and readable. SO has easy to use formatting. Check your grammar too: "I am validation string"... Don't let SO look messy, we love this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Regex, `\w` stands for letters, underscores and numbers. So you can test using:

```
If (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\w+ Ticket Update- ID:\w+ with Priority:\w+ A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD\.$") {
}
```

If it has to be the same word three times you can use an earlier matched group by its number `\n`:

```
If (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(\w+) Ticket Update- ID:\1 with Priority:\1 A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD\.$") {
}
```

If you want to allow varying spaces, you can use `\s*` which stands for any number of spaces or `\s+` for at least one space:

```
If (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\s*\w+\s+Ticket Update- ID\s*:\s*\w+\s+with Priority\s*:\s*\w+\s+A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD\.$") {
}
```

Comment: it would match `qqqqqq Ticket Update- ID:Old with Priority:Abc A Xyz ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.`, if I am not wrong...

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: Added a solution where the **AnyWordWithNumbers** must be the same all three times. (I'm not sure whether it's what the OP wants.)

Comment: You probably want `^` and `$` too in order to limit it to the exact string, otherwise a string with trailing data would be marked as valid

Comment: Thank you for the reply,

qqqqqq Ticket Update- ID:Old with Priority:Abc A Xyz ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD. this is working


But Not this :
qqq Ticket Update- ID: ajadhh with Priority:new A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

Why so,

Comment: Also you want to escape the final full stop because otherwise it matches any char after `GSD`

Comment: AnyWordWithNumbers  is not same it can be any thing

Comment: @Jegan: It will *also* match words constisting of only digits, but not *only*. If the OP wants the word to start with a character or he wants numbers only at the end of the word, then he would have to specify that.

Comment: Can we make string with no Dyanamic word as valid : 
For Example:- Ticket Update- ID: with Priority: A ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

And secondly can we make if dyamic word is only white space valid:
For example :     Ticket Update- ID:    with Priority:     A ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

Note : space can be of any number..ex 2,3,4 spaces

Comment: You can replace `w+` which means "at least one word character" by `w*` which means "any number of word characters, including zero". Since we have a `\s*` in front of the word, the requirement that the word may consist of only spaces is fulfilled already. I recommend http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorial.

Comment: Can we make whole string for ex :"Dear Alamelu, as per your request CHN - CCO-Tandberg Room 4 has been booked for 18-Jun-2013 from 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM." as a dynamic string in place of "AnyWordWithNumbers",
It is not working with \w...

Ex template string is  :

  Ticket Update-Dear Alamelu, as per your request CHN - CCO-Tandberg Room 4 has been booked for 18-Jun-2013 from 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM. ID:AnyWordWithNumbers with Priority:AnyWordWithNumbers A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

Comment: `.*?` stands for any number (including zero) of any character. `.+?` stands for at least one character. The `?` means as few characters as possible, because otherwise the `.*` or `.+` might swallow too many characters. So replace `\w*` by `.*?` and `\w+` by `.+?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex:

```
private static readonly Regex TestRegex = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z0-9]+) Ticket Update- ID:\1 with Priority:\1 A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD\.$");

public bool IsValid(string testString)
{ 
   return (TestRegex.IsMatch(testString));
}
```

Comment: Obviously you can change the first `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` if you want a more restrictive match e.g. cant start with a number could be `([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)`

Answer (score 0):

The below method will give you the expected result.

```
static bool IsMatch(string templateString, string input)
{
    string[] splittedStr = templateString.Split('#');
    string regExString = splittedStr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < splittedStr.Length; i++)
    {
        regExString += "[\\w\\s]*" + splittedStr[i];
    }

    Regex regEx = new Regex(regExString);
    return regEx.IsMatch(input);
}
```

Use the above method like follows,

```
string templateString = "# Ticket Update- ID:# with Priority:# A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD";
string testString = "New Ticket Update- ID:New with Priority:New A New ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD";
bool test = IsMatch(templateString, testString);
```

Comment: Can we make string with no Dyanamic word as valid : 
For Example:- Ticket Update- ID: with Priority: A ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

And secondly can we make if dyamic word is only white space valid:
For example :     Ticket Update- ID:    with Priority:     A ticket/action item is assigned to you in GSD.

Note : space can be of any number..ex 2,3,4 spaces

Comment: Bob Vale: [\\w\\s]* is matches any word and space.